# How can I convert .osp files to other formats?

Tags: video-conversion

I'm new to Ubuntu. I recorded a video and edited it with OpenShot Video Editor. It was all good. But then I couldn't upload the video because it's format is .osp. I searched how to convert but I didn't find anything.

How can I convert .osp files?

Comment: You need to save it as another format. OpenShot says it can do this.

Comment: I have a ShareX .osp file, it's just a text file around ~100KB in size, but refers to (among other things) a separate mp4 video (try something like `grep -o 'path[^,]*,' file.osp`)

Answer (score 4):

`.osp` is a project file, not a video file.

To create a video you need to -export- your project. See the "file" options:

[image]